# Properly use Java libraries in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I am learning Scala and I am unable to figure out how to **properly use commands from Java libraries in Scala**. I show below what am trying to do in a command-line.

```
collier@Nacho-Laptop:~$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import java.text._
import java.text._                                               ^


scala> println(java.text.DateFormat.getCalendar())
<console>:11: error: value getCalendar is not a member of object java.text.DateFormat
              println(java.text.DateFormat.getCalendar())
                                           ^

scala> println(java.text.getCalendar())
<console>:11: error: object getCalendar is not a member of package java.text
              println(java.text.getCalendar())
                                ^

scala> println(getCalendar())
<console>:11: error: not found: value getCalendar
              println(getCalendar())
                      ^

scala> getCalendar()
<console>:11: error: not found: value getCalendar
              getCalendar()
              ^

scala>
```

Comment: `getCalendar` is not static on `DateFormat`.

Comment: And because of that your problem lies not on the Scala side, but on the Java side. The equivalent Java code would also fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The REPL error messages clearly show that `getCalendar` is not defined for the `DateFormat` class. You can simply call [`Calendar#getInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29)

```
scala> import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Calendar

scala> println(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
```

Answer (score 5):

```
java.text.DateFormat.getCalendar()
```

will not work in Java because `getCalendar` is an instance method of `DateFormat`.

If you want to get a calendar try using [`Calendar.getInstance(Locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28java.util.Locale%29)

Comment: Thanks, but how would I do this in Scala? What do I import and how do I type this?

Comment: import java.util.Calendar         println(Calendar.getInstance)

Comment: @DanW thanks! Okay, I understand how to do this now.